# Windows server 03/08 Data & Service Isolation/Autonomy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I've been taking stand-alone course MOC 6436 Designing Active Directory Infrastructure and It has come to my attention the lab01 ask about extracting the data Isolation/Autonomy and Service Isolation/Autonomy current settings from the forest. But the course doesnt show on how to find out the current settings! Im clear about the theory and what it means but the question here is: How can I find the current data & service settings if they are isolated/autonomy from other administrators? I've investigated thru several pages and forums with sad results.. :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, there aren't specific isolation or autonomy objects in AD.  They are concepts that you implement using permissions and rights and control through group memberships, etc.

As an example, I might assign a particular technician local admin rights to a server to give the autonomy to manage services on that server, without granting domain admins rights to the whole domain.

Data isolation can be implemented using shares or volumes and controlled using ACLs and group memberships.